# Get Firefox to show a checklist of tabs in current session

Tags: firefox

When Firefox crashes and you launch it again, it shows a single tab with a message indicating its embarrassment. In this message, the windows and tabs from the crashed session are shown as a nice checklist, so I can go through the titles and uncheck tabs that I don't need to restore.

[image: Example of Firefox Session restore checklist]

Is there any way to get a similar checklist of tabs for the **currently running session**? It would be very handy when I have too many tabs. Going through the crowded tab bar and cleaning up that way is time-consuming.

It's faster to look through the checklist (which shows a much longer title) and uncheck tabs I no longer need, then hit a button to have Firefox close all the tabs I unchecked. I can also use the keyboard easily on such a checklist: moving up and down to select, and hitting space bar to uncheck.

I tried `about:sessionrestore` but this shows a blank list. The closest I can get to what I want is to use the *Tab Groups* feature (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>) but it shows the tabs as thumbnails, I have to hover mouse to see full title, and closing a tab moves other tabs forward.

Comment: If there isn't an add-on for this then it should be possible to create one, but that's a different discussion and off-topic for this site anyway. Have you tried [this add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/tree-style-tab/) by the way?

Comment: Thanks @Karan that is kinda *not* what I'm looking for. It's a persistent sidebar with tabs listed. I don't want a persistent solution. Yeah I'm surprised there's no add-on for this yet. I don't have add-on development experience. Let's see.